# Why unicode string fails when I am trying to plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

Consider the following code where I like to plot some unicode string but it fails.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='ttf/adorsholipi_20-07-2007.ttf')

plt.title(u'ফিগার প্লট',fontproperties=prop)
plt.text(0.2, 0.8, u'সে স্কুলে যায়', fontproperties=prop)

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib plot]

Comment: It's not obvious what fails here since there is a plot with respective characters shown. Please [edit] your question to include a proper problem description.

Comment: Ok its plot each respective characters, but not in the way it is given. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: It's not clear to me what's wrong. Can you add a picture or add marks to the existing picture what is wrong resp. what you expect?

Comment: its doing "ফ িগার প্ লট" instead of "ফিগার প্লট" and "স ে স্ কুল ে যায়" instead of "সে স্কুলে যায়" @mkiever

Comment: @Md. Zakir Hossan So it's inserting character distances. Is it a Right-to-Left script? Also check your font in a wordprocessing program. Maybe just the font is broken.